# Looking for pointers on a Database-Abstraction-Layer

Tags: c#, database, delegates

I'll start by saying that over the course of a few projects, I have implemented this in two different ways, but have never been satisfied with the results.

NOTE: I do **not** have an interest in using ORMS!

**A background**

I've worked on many projects which have required a database-abstraction-layer for multiple platforms.  Back in the days of classical ASP/VBScript we had a set of functions that encapsulated SQL text to cleanse the data, and then build the string appropriate for the provider (SQL Server, MSSQL, Oracle, DB2, etceteras).

Fast-forward to a few years ago, I wrote a DAL that replaced all that convoluted string stuff with actual objects.  The idea was simple, you derived a database-class from an abstract Database class to handle the opening/closing and execution of things according to the .NET provider.  One also made `Insert`, `Select`, `Update` objects that also worked appropriately for the provider.  Truth be told, although it worked and the software could work with any database through objects and the programmer never had to touch SQL; it was unwieldy.  Introducing a new database platform took time to create all the objects.

Sample code:

```
DB.Database db = DatabasePool.Get();

try
{
    DB.Select select = db.NewSelect("_people"); // MSSQL/Oracle/DB2, doesn't matter
    select.Add("_id");
    select.Add("_people_name");
    select.Where.AndClause("_people_name", DB.Operator.Like, "bob");
    DB.Results results = select.ExecuteToCollection();
    // here, Select is "tailored" to the right DB provider and returns the correct
    // sql.
}
finally
{
    DatabasePool.Release();
}
```

The next iteration improved on this somewhat.  Instead of having an abstract database class and a whole bunch of abstract objects to represent operations, there was a set of *concrete* objects.  Providers then provided a delegate for each type.  Converting objects to SQL was a simple case of throwing it at a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` and the provider knew how to convert that particular object (or indeed, integral type) in to SQL, performing data-cleansing at the same time.  All was good, and I improved accessors to the objects:

```
DB.Database db = DatabasePool.Get();
try
{
    DB.Select select = new Select(db); // now a sealed, concrete object
    select.Add("_id").Add("_people_name");
    select.Where.And("_people_name", DB.Op.Like, "bob");
    DB.Results results = select.Query();

    // much better now.  Select is a sealed object.  The Database class has a bunch of
    // delegates that convert any type (including Select, Delete, int, decimal) to
    // appropriate SQL.  Much less work implementing different providers.
}
finally
{
    DatabasePool.Release();
}
```

**Now**

I have the opportunity now, to do this again (and the project-time to do it).  I guess my question is, is this a good way of going about handling different providers encapsulating database operations in objects?  Whilst delegates work fine:

1) It's easy to write a generator for `Column`, `Select`, `Delete`, `int`, `NULL`, etceteras, but when constructing `WHERE` clauses, I ended up with a bunch of tiny atomic objects that did 'parts' of things.

2) Whilst different flavors of SQL have subtle differences, the majority is the same.  The base-database class provided acceptable defaults for pretty much all of the objects, and different providers just replaced those delegates.  But I didn't see this as very "clear" to the programmer.  It wasn't clear which ones was handled by what layer of code.

Is there a better way?  I am happy with the *concept* of objects replacing writing any SQL whatsoever.  They make it very easy to build SQL statements dynamically, with cleansing and appropriate type conversion from the database type to the .NET type (I have never to deal with database types outside of the database objects, for example.  I always get a DateTime back, System.UInt32, a bool, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you played at all with LINQ to SQL?  It's not really a full-featured ORM, but it does represent a fluent model for the representation of database operations.  Even if you didn't want to use LINQ to SQL, you could consider writing your own LINQ provider that's more to your taste.  This has the advantage that developers who already have familiarity with LINQ could use your system without much additional learning curve.  If you don't already have familiarity, read up on [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).  LINQ was designed pretty much to do exactly what you're describing and a lot of work went into allowing for very flexible and natural representation of queries.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will have a look at that.  How would this also handle encapsulating the creation/amendment of tables/columns, deletes, inserts and updates?  The DAL I've made provided objects to do all of these things without worrying about the underlying syntax.

Comment: LINQ can only represent the Query portion of these statements, so you'd need to define your own mechanism to interpret the query in the context of a DELETE or UPDATE, for instance (the query construct is still very useful to specify what to DELETE and which records to UPDATE.)

Comment: Hi Dan, I've been doing a bit of digging and I thinm that LINQ might nicely satisfy the WHERE parts of my objects and that integrating the two may be the way to go here.  I guess my last question on this is, given the LINQ queries I see posted here all the time, how is this converted to SQL currently and is there an abstraction layer behind already to deal with different providers?  Thanks! :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice, Note that most of the LINQ queries you see posted are actually against LINQ to Objects, which is simply queries against collections of objects in memory.  As far as I know, the only SQL LINQ Provider included with .NET is for MS SQL Server.  However, there are a whole wide range of other implementations available: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/02/28/link-to-everything-a-list-of-linq-providers.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I think I can find a balance between the objects, and LINQ. :)